# Why does my imported Maven project throw incompatible type error when the types match exactly?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to call this method in my main project which is being imported using Maven
public void updateCreoParams(ComponentFeat compFeat, Model model)

But when I call it like (1) it throws an error on build (2)
(1)creoParams.updateCreoParams(compFeat, null);

- compFeat is of the type ComponentFeat

(2)Error:(216, 61) java: incompatible types: com.ptc.pfc.pfcComponentFeat.ComponentFeat cannot be converted to java.util.List<[package].Parameter>

List is a variable that is set for the class in the constructor, if that makes a difference.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

****UPDATE****

Here is the Class that is causing the issue. I expect it to work but for some reason the error above is thrown on build, even though the method being called doesnt take List as a parameter

```
public class CreoParameters {
    ArrayList<String> parameterList;
    List<Parameter> params;
    /**
     * Initialize this object with a list of parameters that you want to put onto the model
     * @param params
     */
    public CreoParameters(List<Parameter> params){
        this.params = params;
        parameterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<params.size(); i++){
            parameterList.add(params.get(i).parameterName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the Parameters in Creo for a given assembly component, and a list of Params
     * @param compFeat
     * @param model
     * @author jcesson
     */
    public void updateCreoParams(ComponentFeat compFeat, Model model) {
        try {
            ParameterOwner modelToUpdate;
            if(compFeat != null) {
                modelToUpdate = compFeat;
            }else if(model != null){
                modelToUpdate = model;
            }else{
                modelToUpdate = null;
                return;
            }
            //Removes old instance of Parameters to be updated
            Parameters oldParams = modelToUpdate.ListParams();
            for(int i=0; i<oldParams.getarraysize(); i++) {
                String oldParamName = oldParams.get(i).GetName();
                if(parameterList.contains(oldParamName)) {
                    oldParams.get(i).Delete();
                }
            }
            oldParams.clear();

            //Adds in the new Parameters
            for(int i=0; i<params.size(); i++) {
                ParamValue newPV = pfcModelItem.CreateStringParamValue(params.get(i).getParameterValue());
                modelToUpdate.CreateParam(params.get(i).getParameterName(), newPV);
            }

        } catch (jxthrowable e) {

            CEWSLogger.info("Bad Creo Model Error "+e.toString());

        }
        
    }
}
```

this is how it is called, and where the error is thrown upon build
neither updatedParams or compFeat are null.

```
private List<Parameter> updatedParams = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
private ComponentFeat compFeat;
.
.
.
CreoParameters creoParams = new CreoParameters(updatedParams);
creoParams.updateCreoParams(compFeat, null);
```

Comment: Without the code it's impossible...

Comment: Please provide the code, then tell us what is working wrong and what you expect it to be working like. It is impossible to help you with only what you have provided us.

Comment: `ComponentFeat` and `List` sure don't look like they match.

Comment: updated to include relavent code

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this problem, it is because of Maven. The Parameters used to include List after updating code an mvn clean was required, thats why when it built it didn't work but the compiler didn't throw any errors. After an mvn clean everything worked as it was supposed to

Comment: First I have my doubts about that furthermore do you use and IDE? Have you simply tried to do `mvn package`? Furthermore Which maven versions/maven-compiler-plugin version etc. are you using?